# Im not able to set global variable in my context provider

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to create a SessionProvider to avoid propdrilling and hold session globally for my components.

Im am not able to set state; `menu.js L:11: setIsLoggedin is not a function`

My custom hook (useSession.js):

```
import { useState } from 'react'

function useSession(isLoggedInState) {

    const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(isLoggedInState);

    return { isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn, }
}

export default useSession;
```

My provider (SessionContext.js):

```
import React, { createContext, useState } from 'react'
import useSession from '../hooks/useSession'

const SessionContext = createContext();

function SessionProvider({ children, isLoggedin = false }) {

    const { isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn } = useSession(isLoggedin);

    return (
        <SessionContext.Provider value={isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn}>{children}</SessionContext.Provider>
    )
}

export { SessionProvider, SessionContext };
```

I've wrapped my application using  in _app.js and then in Home (index.js) I try to use it there:

```
import { useContext } from "react";
import { SessionContext } from "../contexts/SessionContext";

export default function Menu(props) {

    const { setIsLoggedIn } = useContext(SessionContext)

    function onButtonClick(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        setIsLoggedIn(true)
    }

    return (
        <><span onClick={onButtonClick}>Login</span></>
    )
}
```

Im able to read isLoggedIn, but not set it?

Comment: Any chance it's a typo? - perhaps that bit in your `Menu` should be `setIsLoggedIn(true)` instead of `setIsLoggedin(true)`?

Comment: Hey @AndrewMack, it was a typo. I changed it but I still go the same result!

Answer (score 0):

Your import into SessionContext should be

```
import useSession from '../hooks/useSession'
```

because you use

```
export default useSession;
```

More explaination here
https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export

if you installed any linter into your ide, the errors should be underlined.

Comment: I made the change to the code, but it still states that setIsLoggedIn is not a function